# Fixed action bar similar to the Facebook app

Tags: android

I have implemented the action bar (not the quick action bar) in my app. The action bar is based on the one used in the Google IO app and the Facebook app. I am stumped though, trying to understand how to keep the action bar fixed. When an activity needs scrolling, the action bar needs to be remain fixed. Can anyone help with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some good stuff in Jon's post, but if you're just looking for the simple answer to work with your existing layouts/activities, just use a vertical `LinearLayout` with the first child as the titlebar and the second as the ScrollView, setting the ScrollView height to `fill_parent` (or setting [`fillViewport`](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/) to true). Alternatively, use a RelativeLayout with the scrollview set to layout below the title, or with a top margin on the scrollview equal to the height of the title bar.

Answer (score 1):

I'm developing an open-source app that is adapted from Google IO. I made a generic version of the titlebar that they used - called `CustomTitlebarActivity`  which subclasses `Activity`.

As an example, I'll refer you to my `HomeActivity` implementation which subclasses `CustomTitlebarActivity`; since I abstract the titlebar away from the activity's layout, you can easily add a `ScrollView` below it that will not scroll the titlebar out of view.

An added benefit to this design choice is a lot more code re-use than Google IO had, with some ..quirks that are easily circumvented. I won't go into that in more detail here though.

### HomeActivity

res:

http://code.google.com/p/electricsleep/source/browse/beta/res/layout/activity_home.xml

src:

http://code.google.com/p/electricsleep/source/browse/beta/src/com/androsz/electricsleepbeta/app/HomeActivity.java

### CustomTitlebarActivity

res:

http://code.google.com/p/electricsleep/source/browse/beta/res/layout/titlebar.xml

src:

http://code.google.com/p/electricsleep/source/browse/beta/src/com/androsz/electricsleepbeta/app/CustomTitlebarActivity.java

Also, I have one activity that has a scrollview inside it, (though it is inside a ViewFlipper) in case you have trouble. Check out the res:

http://code.google.com/p/electricsleep/source/browse/beta/res/layout/wizard_welcome.xml

Comment: Hiya Jon. Your suggestions really are amazing, but from my point of view, Yoni's suggestion was far simpler. Your suggestions though will be useful in another app I had in mind for a while. Will use bits of them in that. Thanks a lot nonetheless. It certainly will be of help.